# How to Set 'Play' Button Behavior on Bluetooth Remote

Tags: bluetooth, music, audio

I have a RocketFish Bluetooth headset paired with my MotoDROID v1 (Froyo).  The BT headphones have multimedia controls (volume up/down, next track, previous track, play/pause) and a button to trigger voice dialing.  I have it paired both on the handsfree headset profile and the advanced audio profile.

When I click the play button on my headphones, the behavior is unpredictable.  I might have the Music app up, but clicking play will cause Listen to launch and begin playing a podcast.  I might have Listen in the foreground, but clicking play will cause the Music player to start playing from a playlist.  Other times, the play button will behave as expected and cause the app in the foreground to play.

Is there any way (outside of rooting my device) that I can indicate which app should be acting on these button presses?

Comment: I've played with a couple of other apps.  I notice that DoubleTwist has a setting to set the app as the default recipient for headset controls, but it doesn't seem to work.  Same for Cubed (3).  Is this just a busted feature, or is there some hidden setting I haven't found?

Comment: I had a similar experience with a Sony MW600 headset on my Droid; I think this may have been an issue with how FroYo handles the bluetooth buttons.   It seems much better (although occasionally no app responds to play) on my Droid Bionic running Gingerbread.

Answer (score 1):

Normaly the developer can set which button do which action. So it is different from app to app. 
 The only way is, sorry, rooting and remap your headset buttons.