# What determines the audio source android resumes?

Tags: audio, android-11, bluetooth-audio, audio-controls

I'm looking for information on what criteria is used when android resumes an audio source.  The more technical the better.

I would have assumed it was whatever the last playing source was, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It doesn't even seem to be the last source that that device had active.  For example I was listening to an audio book in the car, but the next time I get back in it resumes a podcast.

It really seems almost random.

Thank you.

Comment: [Audio focus request](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFocusRequest) should help I guess// Obtain a log cat and search for apps that get audio focus - maybe that will give some pointers. This is my understanding as a non-developer

Comment: It's not about Android but the app you are using for audio playback.

Comment: Possible related/dupe? [What determines which application acts to a Bluetooth AVRCP command?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13620/44325)